# How to get the character index and character in given string using mouse hover in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the following code.

```
<div class="clickDv" style="width:150px;border:1px solid red;">This is a simple example</div>
```

And java script code is following:

```
$('div.clickDv').click( function () {
    getCharPos(); 
});

function getCharPos() {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    console.log(selection.focusNode.data[selection.focusOffset]);
    console.log(selection.focusOffset);
}
```

If we click on the any character given in string, It returns the string index and character as well. But how can I achieve this using .hover().

If i replace `.click()` to `.hover()`,and hovering the characters in the div then `window.getSelection()` gives the "null".

So there is any other way to achieve this.

Comment: The only solution I could imagine would involve (perhaps temporarily) wrapping each character in a `<span>` and retrieving the index of that element amongst its siblings.

Comment: window.getSelection() returns the item that is selected. If you are hovering, then the item will not be selected, therefore null will be returned...

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getSelection getSelection gives u the selected. Where as hover is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the lettering.js plugin (https://raw.github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js/master/jquery.lettering.js), which wraps letters (or words or lines) in span elements.

This way you can easily target them and use .position() on those elements to get their actual location in their container (which should have position:relative)..

Demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/rT3zn/2/

HTML:

```
<strong>by word</strong>
<div class="mycooldiv words">bunch of text is in here and for example some # and some other cool #</div>

<strong>by letters</strong>
<div class="mycooldiv letters">bunch of text is in here and for example some # and some other cool #</div>

<div id="position"></div>
```

JS:

```
var $pos = $('#position');

$('.mycooldiv.words')
    .lettering('words')
    .delegate('span', 'mouseover', function(e){
        var self = $(this);
        var position = self.position();

        self.addClass('active');
        $pos.text('x:' + position.left+ ', y:' + position.top + ', content: ' + self.text())
    })
    .delegate('span', 'mouseout',  function(e){
        var self = $(this);
        self.removeClass('active');
    });


$('.mycooldiv.letters')
    .lettering()
    .delegate('span', 'mouseover', function(e){
        var self = $(this);
        var position = self.position();

        self.addClass('active');
        $pos.text('x:' + position.left+ ', y:' + position.top + ', content: ' + self.text())
    })
    .delegate('span', 'mouseout',  function(e){
        var self = $(this);
        self.removeClass('active');
    })
```

Comment: I think there is some problem in fiddle code because it is throwing some console error("Object [object Object] has no method 'lettering' ").

Comment: Works for me. Maybe you use IE? IE is known not to get along with jsfiddle well (i.e. jsfiddle does not support IE)

Comment: Indeed, it does not work in Chrome. I don't know why. Probably some minor issue. I will leave it up to you to find out what's going on. The code/idea is correct.

Comment: Working Fine on Firefox 26.0.