# jQuery get the character (characters must include html) index of a char at mouse coordinates in a normal div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the character index under the pointer icon of the mouse at a mousedown/mouseup event/or click event in a standard div.

if i get the index, it must include  all the spaces and html characters to output the index.

or

if i can get all the html from the 0 index of the div to the point of click, this will also surfice.

I have looked for this for days now.. i on many occasions almost had it, but just nothing worked..

if i get the html to the left of the point of click i can work out the index myself

or

as a last resort if i can get the word under the point of click, that i could maybe work with too..

thanks in advance..

UPDATE:

Ive come up with this pice of code: its a combination of sorts of research.. The problem here is if the word or character is a duplicate, then the first character is indexed, otherwise it works..

```
`function getSelectionHtml() {
var html = "";
if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount) {
        var container = document.createElement("div");
        for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
            container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
        }
        html = container.innerHTML;
    }
} else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
    if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
        html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
    }
}
var gt =$('#test').html().indexOf(html)
return gt;
```

}`

Comment: please explain what you try to do. why do you have to geht the index?

Answer (score 0):

i did also try this code, found here, but it behaved oddly with 
 or new lines, otherwise it came close to getting the index..

[How to get the character index and character in given string using mouse hover in Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114155/how-to-get-the-character-index-and-character-in-given-string-using-mouse-hover-i)

Comment: Did you mean to comment on your own question, or is this the actual answer?